# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'customerName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

My **JSON** file looks like this:

```
{
    "total": 3,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "01",
            "data": {
                "customerName": "Jhon",
                "description": "..some content..",
                "price": "25000"
            },
            "status": "Yes"
        },
        {
            "id": "02",
            "data": {
                "customerName": "Mark",
                "description": "..some content..",
                "price": "30000"
            },
            "status": "No"
        },
        {
            "id": "03",
            "data": {
                "customerName": "Smith",
                "description": "..some content..",
                "price": "15000"
            },
            "status": "No"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am displaying the them in an component called `list` like this:

**ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contacts.service';
import { ICustomer } from '../models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  public allCustomers: any = [];
   public customers: any = [];
  constructor(private myService: ContactService) { }

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.allCustomers = await this.myService.getCustomers('');
    this.customers = this.allCustomers.items;
    console.log( this.customers.data.customerName);
  }


}
```

**template**

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <p>{{customer.data.customerName}}</p>
    <p>{{customer.data.price}}</p>
</div>
```

Now i am able to display the values(customerName, price ..) in template:

[image]

But when i `log` and see the same values(customerName, price ..), showing as **undefined**.

[image]

I am unable find what went wrong.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-gvvvjq?file=src/app/list/list.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the Safe Navigation Operator to handle the undefined error

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <p>{{customer?.data?.customerName}}</p>
    <p>{{customer?.data?.price}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have that error because you are accessing array value by object

```
console.log( this.customers.data.customerName); // this are array value
```

so if you want to see the data you have to do like this

```
 console.log( this.customers[0].data.customerName); // this are array value
```

Comment: How can i log all customers? Now i am able log only one.

Comment: Same as you did in the html, with a foreach-loop: `for (const customer of this.customers) {console.log(customer.data.customerName);}`

Answer (score 0):

you are returning an array of objects, knowing that array index starts from zero.
This will work

`console.log(this.customers[index].data.customerName);`

Change the "index" to either 0,1,2 to get the customerName of the first,second or third object respectively

Comment: Getting this error `ReferenceError: index is not defined
ReferenceError: index is not defined`

Comment: change the word [index] to 0 or 1 or 2 to get the customerName of the first,second or third object respectively. Eg console.log(this.customers[index].data.customerName);

Comment: Sorry I meant console.log(this.customers[2].data.customerName) not console.log(this.customers[index].data.customerName)

Answer (score 0):

**this.customers** is an array element.

Use forEach() to list each element. [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
this.customers.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element.data.customerName);
});
```